# ActiveMQ - Stomp + NIO

Tags: activemq

I currently use ActiveMQ to serve a STOMP message queue with several topics. As we are now starting to get several thousand connections to the queue, I have been trying to implement NIO to reduce the number of threads used.

Following the documentation, I have modified my configuration to add NIO as follows:

However, when testing I am still getting two threads per connection - one named NIO Transport Thread and another named BrokerService.

I was expecting thread use to be much lower using NIO. Therefore - am I wrong in my expectations, or are there more configuration changes required for NIO?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a quick flick through the ActiveMQ Developer Forums, it appears that there has been a few architectural issues with the way the Stomp transport has historically been implemented in AMQ.

It looks like [issue AMQ-2386](https://issues.apache.org/activemq/browse/AMQ-2386) may potentially resolve the problem you seem to be experiencing and it might be best checking out a revision >= 813722 of the ActiveMQ trunk to see if it fixes your problem?